# Get author Meta for particular user inside the loop

Tags: loop, user-meta

I am using this code to get the meta for the current author in the loop.

```
 get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ), 120);
```

How can I modify this to get the meta for a particular user ID? I tried for example to get the image for userID: 4 but this didn't work.

```
get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( '4' ), 120);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `get_the_author_meta('ID')` will return the ID of the author for the current post.

That means this line should work.

`get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ), 120);`

This will not work

```
get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( '4' ), 120);
```

Because you are trying to get a property named '4' inside the user object and that property doesn't exist.

If you wanted to get the avatar for user 4 you would use.

```
get_avatar( 4, 120);
```

Because get_avatar takes either a `$user_id` or `$email` as the first parameter and the `$size` as the second.

On a final note the WordPress documentation uses, so check for a formatting error in your html.

```
get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ), 32 );
```